# Numerically stable normalizing for vectors of small magnitudes

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-stability

The context of the problem is that I have a resnet model in Jax (basically NumPy), and I  take the gradient of an image with respect to its class prediction. This gives me a gradient vector, `g`, which I then want to normalize. The trouble is, the magnitudes of the components, `g[i]`, are such that `g[i]**2 == 0`, meaning that just dividing by `np.linalg.norm(g)` gives a value of `0`, hence giving me `nan`s.

What I've done so far is just checking if the norm is 0 then multiplying by some constant factor, as in (`g = np.where(np.linalg.norm(g) < 1e-20, g * 1e20, g)`).

Was thinking maybe I should instead divide by the smallest nonzero element then normalize. Does anyone have ideas on how to properly normalize this vector?

Comment: Can u share the implementation you tried out ?

Comment: Also am trying out doing something like g = np.where(np.linalg.norm(g) == 0, g * np.finfo(np.float32).max, g), where np.finfo(np.float32).max gives the max value for a float32 in NumPy. Note that if the norm of g is 0, then we won't have to worry about overflow as individual components << 1.